# How to make this grammar LL(1)?

Tags: compiler-construction

I had this grammar at first.

```
S -> A | B
A -> Aa | epsilon
B -> Bb | epsilon
```

I eliminated left recursion to have this:

```
S -> A | B
A -> A'
A' -> aA' | epsilon
B -> B'
B' -> bB' | epsilon
```

This grammar is not LL(1) as First(A) and First(B) have epsilon in common. I know that common first symbols are usually resolved with factoring. I do not know how to resolve common epsilon in A and B First sets.

Comment: epsilon is *not* a normal symbol

Comment: @CapelliC This is exactly the reason I asked my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grammar is ambiguous, since an empty string could be produced by either *S*→*A*→ε or *S*→*B*→ε. In order to make the grammar parseable at all, you need to resolve the ambiguity.

Probably the simplest would be to add the rule *S*→ε and then remove it from both *A* and *B*, so that their base productions are *a* and *b* respectively.